# Intersect two layers and get resulting features

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-server, c#, spatial-join

I have X layers on a map and I need to intersect chosen layers (two per time) and color resulting features.

I'm trying to get this code working

```
// get first feature (index 0)
ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Geometry.Geometry adfFeature =
                m_firstLayer.GeometryFromRow(m_firstLayer.Rows[0]) 
as ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Geometry.Geometry;

// THE FOLLOWING LINE RETURNS NULL
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometry featureInterface = adfFeature as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometry;

ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ITopologicalOperator topoOp = adfFeature as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ITopologicalOperator;
```

How to use the IGeometry interface with an ADF Geometry object?

I can't really find samples to intersect features between two layers, and it's a pity that Spatial Joins are just a arcgis desktop function, I surely could use them!

Help please